# Is it possible to access the credentials a Windows service was created with?

Tags: winapi

I am investigating some code that creates a service with ::CreateService API call:

```
SC_HANDLE hService = ::CreateService(
    hSCM, m_szServiceName, _T(ALE_SERVICE_NAME),
    SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS, SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,
    SERVICE_AUTO_START/*SERVICE_DEMAND_START*/, SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,
    szFilePath, NULL, NULL, _T("RPCSS\0"), (LPCTSTR)name, g_pwd.c_str());
```

`name` and `g_pwd` are the user name and password the app user specified installing the app.

1) Where Windows stores user name and password?

2) Is it possible to access user name and password after the service is created? (This will eliminate the need to reenter the credentials when the product is updated and the service executable probably moved to another location).

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/777233/where-and-how-is-the-password-stored-for-the-account-associated-with-a-windows-s

Comment: @AlexK. I installed the app, now the service is listed in Services and I can start/stop it, but the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY` is empty (there is no `Policy' sub-key.)

Comment: @AlexK. probably it is not empty, but hidden.

Comment: @AlexK.I found it, the key really is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY\Policy\Secrets\_SC_MyService

Comment: @AlexK. I tried Get-TSLSASecret script, it shown user name, but not password. See https://developernote.com/2019/11/accessing-a-service-credentials-on-windows-10/ for more information on what experimentation I did.

Comment: Maybe a account doesn't require a password helps? ([LocalService Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/localservice-account)) Do you have any other concern?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT The account is the domain administrator that has the password.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT is not the password is stored in some SAM file?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky The Security Accounts Manager (SAM) is a database that stores local user accounts and groups. However, when a computer is joined to a domain, Active Directory manages domain accounts in Active Directory domains. Refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/windows-authentication/credentials-processes-in-windows-authentication).